Why does ?zcli_apps=true do nothing in some zendesk orgs?
When I run
zcli apps:server

and I can goto my https://myorg.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/61?zcli_apps=true
and see my app in local dev mode no problem.
But I'm working in another client's org and the same thing doesn't work. I just get no apps on the right side with ?zcli_apps=true
But removing the ?zcli_apps=true and I see my installed version of the app just fine.
Is this an org setting that needs to be turned on?

I think this may have to do with the profile that you are using.  ZCLI authenticates against each account that you want to use and will run the server in that instance.
You can check which account you are using by running zcli profiles:list.  You can add the new account by running zcli login -i.  Use zcli profiles:use [name] to switch between accounts.
See the Zendesk developer documentation here or the Github documentation here for ZCLI here for more information.
